# hammer.js - problems with user-select css property on windows phone

Tags: windows-phone, hammer.js

If you use hammer.js you may get some problems with text-selection on touch devices (text selection is not working any more). To avoid this behaviour you can remove this option (see http://hammerjs.github.io/tips/):

```
delete Hammer.defaults.cssProps.userSelect;
```

This works, EXCEPT on window phones. Here I cannot find any solution to make text-selection possible.

Any solutions or hacks???